# re.sub(...) replacing leftmost occurrences?

Tags: python, regex

`$ pydoc re.sub` :

```
sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
    Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    replacement repl.

>>> re.sub('ROAD', 'RD.', 'BRRROADBBRROAD ROAD ROAD MY ROAD')
'BRRRD.BBRRD. RD. RD. MY RD.'
```

I don't quite understand the meaning of leftmost in the python documentation. As far as I can see, it seems `re.sub(...)` is replacing *all* occurrences of `pattern` with `repl`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note the 's' ending *leftmost non-overlapping occurrences*.

`re.sub` replaces all occurrences. You can use the optional *count* argument to limit the amount of replacements it does.

"Leftmost non-overlapping" means that if several occurrences are overlapping and can be potentially replaced, only the leftmost will:

```
>>> str = 'AABBBBAA'
>>> re.sub('BBB', 'CCC', str)
'AACCCBAA'
```

As you can see, there two (overlapping) occurrences of `BBB` here. Only the leftmost is replaced.

Answer (score 5):

You can see what leftmost means in this example

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('haha', 'Z', 'hahaha')
'Zha'
```

Note we did not see 'haZ' which would have been rightmost substitution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you do a rightmost substitution? What about other languages like Javascript, do they also do a leftmost replacement?

Comment: Leftmost replacement is universal, as far as I know.  To do a rightmost replacement, use `rfind` (in Python) or `lastIndexOf` (in JavaScript) and just splice in the replacement string at that point.